# grep all Gentoo Stage3 links to the terminal

Tags: sed, grep, wget

I want to display all links from `https://www.gentoo.org/downloads/mirrors/` to the terminal.

Firstly, the script would `wget` the web page to a file called `index.html`, then a `grep` or `sed` command would simply display all the `https://`, `http://` and `ftp://` to the terminal.

Can someone help me with this command? I know it's simple, but I'm not really familiar with neither of these commands.

What i tried:
`grep "<code>" index.html`

Output:

```html
              <a href="ftp://mirrors.tera-byte.com/pub/gentoo"><code>ftp://mirrors.tera-byte.com/pub/gentoo</code></a>
              <a href="http://gentoo.mirrors.tera-byte.com/"><code>http://gentoo.mirrors.tera-byte.com/</code></a>
              <a href="rsync://mirrors.tera-byte.com/gentoo"><code>rsync://mirrors.tera-byte.com/gentoo</code></a>
```

How can I remove the empty spaces, tags and all unnecessary text after the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the domain link to remain, you can try this `grep`

```
grep -Eo '[h|f]t*ps?://.[^<|>|"]*' index.html
```

This will display only `http`,`https` and `ftp` matches

If the need is to match within `<code>` blocks, this `sed` will work

```
sed -En '/<code>/ {s|.*([h|f]t*ps?://.[^<|>|"]*).*|\1|p}' index.html
```

Comment: The second command (for whatever reason) displays links that are not associated with the `<code>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep with this pattern:

`grep -Po "(?<=<code>)(https?|ftp)(.*)(?=<\/code>)" index.html`

Top 3 lines of output:

```
ftp://mirrors.tera-byte.com/pub/gentoo
http://gentoo.mirrors.tera-byte.com/
ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gentoo-distfiles/
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only removes the empty spaces. I also want to remove the tags and only want to display the link (either one is fine because they're the same, no matter what tag it's in).

Comment: Thank you for spending time on my question, though personally I use Gentoo, and Perl (by default) is not built-in my version of grep, thus I cannot rely on this command.